# C++ template argument-dependent lookup

Tags: c++, c++11

```
namespace Test {
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T a) {
        g(a);
    }

    struct L {
        int s;
    };

    void bar(L a) {
        g(a);
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(Test::L{1});
    g(Test::L{5});
}

namespace Test {
    void g(L a) {};
}
```

why in foo, g can be found, but in bar and main, g cannot be found.
Tested with gcc 11.2.0 under C++11.Here is the error message.

```
/tmp/tmp.l8jCE9nUHA/test1.cpp: In function ‘void Test::bar(Test::L)’:
/tmp/tmp.l8jCE9nUHA/test1.cpp:33:9: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
   33 |         g(a);
      |         ^
/tmp/tmp.l8jCE9nUHA/test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/tmp.l8jCE9nUHA/test1.cpp:39:5: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
   39 |     g(Test::L{5});
      |     ^
```

Comment: In `foo`, `a` is template dependent, and it should wait instantiation to call the correct one, if any.

Comment: [dependent names lookup rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#:~:text=lookup%20takes%20place.-,Lookup%20rules,-As%20discussed%20in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without the call to `g` in `main` and `bar`, the program is still ill-formed, but with no diagnostic required.

The argument-dependent lookup in a template specialization is done from the point of instantiation of the specialization, not from the point of the definition of the template.

The specialization `Test::foo<Test::L>` is implicitly instantiated due to the call `foo(Test::L{1});` in `main`. As a consequence it has two points of instantiation: One directly after the definition of `main` and one at the end of the translation unit. (This is always the case for function template specializations.)

At the first point of instantiation `Test::g` has not been declared yet and argument-dependent lookup would fail. At the second point of instantiation it would succeed since `Test::g` has been declared there and can be found through argument-dependent lookup via the `Test::L` argument.

If two points of instantiation give different meaning to the program, the program is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required), meaning that it is still an invalid program, but the compiler doesn't have to tell you about it, analogues to ODR violations.

---

To avoid this you should declare all functions `g` that `Test::foo<Test::L>` would potentially use *before* the namespace scope declaration which is first making a call to `Test::foo<Test::L>` (or making some other ODR-use of it). Here this means you should declare `g` before `main`'s definition.

---

The calls `g(Test::L{5});` in `main` and `g(a);` in `bar` simply make the program ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, because neither appears in the definition of a templated entity, so argument-dependent lookup is done directly from where these calls appear and both of these are before `g` has been declared, so that no `g` can be found. To make them work `g` must be declared before these calls.

Comment: *"Even without the call to `g` in `main` and `bar`, the program is still ill-formed, but with no diagnostic required."* **Without** calls to `g` in `main` and `bar`, there are no instantiations of `foo` and so, I don't see where program is ill-formed. (with any of them, we agree that the program is ill-formed NDR).

Comment: @Jarod42 I meant the case where `main` is defined as `int main() { foo(Test::L{1}); }` and `bar` is defined as `void bar(L a) { }`. I want to explain the behavior of the call `foo(Test::L{1});` specifically, since I assumed it was relatively clear why the other two calls to `g` don't work. (Maybe I should have added comments about them as well.)